# How to simulate a Click on Listview Item?

Tags: android, listview, nullreferenceexception

I try to simulate a Click on the first Item of Listview by **OnResume**

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null).performClick();
```

but I get the Error ***on a null object reference***

```
android.view.View android.widget.ListAdapter.getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: the problem maybe the Listview needs time to load the data from database

Comment: I have fixed  the problem, I have added the code in the correct place, where and after the listview finished loading its data. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null).performClick();
      }
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: i get no error ok,it but does not work.
at the moment, I have fixedthe problem after I have moved the code from **OnResume** to the line after the listview finishsloading the data from database :`listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null).performClick();`